# How can I verify that a private method was called in my public method using PowerMockito

Tags: unit-testing, powermockito

I am using Mockito and PowerMock when needed. Right now I need to verify that a private method was called but it's void and I can't find any other questions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

, in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

> How can I verify that a private method was called in my public method

You don't!

UnitTests verify the *public observable behavior* of the code under test.

The  *public observable behavior* of the CUT includes the *return values* and the *communication with its dependencies*.

the use of *private* method is an *implementation detail* which you don't want to test since it may be changed during *refactorings* without changing the CUTs behavior.

Comment: Nice to see that your first thought is to talk sense to the OP ;-)